Farrow filter - Effect of Delta Delay
Looking at the Farrow structure we see that the closer the specific FIR block to the output, the less effect the Delta has on it.

When the output of H4 isn't effected at all by the value of the Delta Delay.
In other words, if Delta = 0, Y(n) will be equal to the output of H4.
What's so special about the last FIR (H4) ? What does it represent ?

it represents the undelayed path in the Farrow structure. It's not more or less special than any other path. Why do you presume it needs to be special?

It's not necessarily undelayed.  For a 4-point Farrow filter, let's say that it's either 3rd-order Lagrange or 3rd-order Hermite. $h_4[n]$ will be a 1-sample delay.  That is because the interpolation is always happening between $x[n-1]$ and $x[n-2]$, with $x[n-0]$ and $x[n-3]$ being the outlier samples.

So when Delta = 0, the output will be x[n−2] ?
And when Delta = 1, the output will be x[n−1] ?

No, I think if $\Delta$ means fractional delay, then when $\Delta = 0$, it means $y[n]=x[n-t]$.  But you can define the 4 $h_k[n]$ so that your $\Delta$ is backwards and $\Delta=0$ means $y[n] = x[n-2]$

What does x[n−t] mean ? Maybe you meant x[n-1] ?

Yes that was a typo that I missed.  And I can't fix typos in comments after 5 minutes.  Thanks for spotting it.  It's supposed to be $x[n-1]$.

The Farrow structure is an efficient way to approximate a set if impulse responses that are dependent on a single parameter. The most common (but not only) application is a variable fractional delay where the fractional delay is the parameter.
The Farrow structure is a polynomial approximation at one sample time over all impulse responses using the parameter as the polynomial variable, i.e.
$$h[n,\Delta] \approx h_f[n_0,\Delta] = \sum_{k=0}^{K-1} \Delta^k \cdot h_k[n_0] \tag{1} $$
The Farrow impulse responses $h_k[n] $ are determined by a least square error optimization at each sample time.

What does it represent ?

Since the process involves a least square error optimization that's not a particularly useful question. Mathematically it's the $0^{th}$ order polynomial component or simply the mean over all impulse responses. In practice you will find that it does look mostly like a delayed unit impulse, but that's simply a byproduct of the least square error process: Having it look like something else would simply result in a larger error so it's not "least" anymore.
If you want a 0 delay to be perfect, you can "hardwire" that impulse response to delayed unit impulse and run the least square optimization with that impulse response as an additional side constraint.

My spin on the Farrow filter structure is that it's an expression of polynomial interpolation using Horner's method to evaluate the polynomial efficiently.  So, take for instance the Cubic Hermite Spline:
$$\begin{align}
 x(n+\Delta) &\approx \tfrac12 \Big(\big((-x[n-1] + 3x[n] - 3x[n+1] + x[n+2]) \Delta \\
& \qquad + (2x[n-1] - 5x[n] + 4x[n+1] - x[n+2])\big)\Delta \\
& \qquad \qquad + (-x[n-1] + x[n+1])\Big)\Delta \quad + \quad x[n] \\
\end{align}$$
Where $0 \le \Delta < 1$.
Here, we have 2 future samples and two past samples.  And $\Delta$ is in the opposite direction as delay.  So let's flip it around:
$$\begin{align}
 x(n-\Delta) &\approx \tfrac12 \Big(\big((-x[n+1] + 3x[n] - 3x[n-1] + x[n-2]) \Delta \\
& \qquad + (2x[n+1] - 5x[n] + 4x[n-1] - x[n-2])\big)\Delta \\
& \qquad \qquad + (-x[n+1] + x[n-1])\Big)\Delta \quad + \quad x[n] \\
\end{align}$$
And again $0 \le \Delta < 1$.
But that's still is looking at one sample into the future, so to make it a causal filter we bump it over one sample.
$$\begin{align}
 x(n-1-\Delta) = x\big(n - (1+\Delta)\big) &\approx \tfrac12 \Big(\big((-x[n] + 3x[n-1] - 3x[n-2] + x[n-3]) \Delta \\
& \qquad + (2x[n] - 5x[n-1] + 4x[n-2] - x[n-3])\big)\Delta \\
& \qquad \qquad + (-x[n] + x[n-2])\Big)\Delta \quad + \quad x[n-1] \\
\end{align}$$
And still $0 \le \Delta < 1$
So this means that the real delay is $$ 1 \le 1+\Delta < 2 $$
Now you have a completely causal filter.  All input samples are either the present sample or the three samples in the immediate past.  Now I hate the numbering system of the FIR filters in the depicted diagram, but using that for $h_1[n] ... h_4[n]$, the four FIR filters are:
$$\begin{align}
 y_1[n] &= \tfrac12 (-x[n] + 3x[n-1] - 3x[n-2] + x[n-3]) \\
 y_2[n] &= \tfrac12 (2x[n] - 5x[n-1] + 4x[n-2] - x[n-3]) \\
 y_3[n] &= \tfrac12 (-x[n] + x[n-2]) \\
 y_4[n] &= x[n-1] \\
\end{align}$$
So
$$\begin{align}
 h_1[n] &= \tfrac12 (-\delta[n] + 3\delta[n-1] - 3\delta[n-2] + \delta[n-3]) \\
 h_2[n] &= \tfrac12 (2\delta[n] - 5\delta[n-1] + 4\delta[n-2] - \delta[n-3]) \\
 h_3[n] &= \tfrac12 (-\delta[n] + \delta[n-2]) \\
 h_4[n] &= \delta[n-1] \\
\end{align}$$
where $\delta[n]$ is the Kronecker delta.
